# Updating SharePoint 2010 from August 2011 CU to Service Pack 2

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, update

I want my SharePoint 2010 farm to update from **August 2011 CU** to **Service Pack 2**.

Just wanted to confirm, do I need to install all of the CU's in between August 2011 CU and SP2? Or just download SP2 Foundation & Server and install one by one (first Foundation and then Server).

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erica/archive/2013/05/30/sharepoint-server-2010-version-reference.aspx) is the list of all CU's and SP's.

Additionally, if anyone has experienced any issues with SP2 or can share link with me for SharePoint 2010 SP2 pros and cons, it will be highly appreciated.

P.S: Please recommend if I need to install any other CU after SP2 installation which is more stable release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I required me to install June 2013 CU first and then SP2 on top of it. June 2013 CU was released later than SP2 and have greater version number. Install them in the same sequence, first Foundation and then Server.

No need to install all of previous CU's for SP2. It includes all of previous CU's in it but not June 2013 CU (as mentioned above).

I experienced an issue that my User Profile Service was unable to start. However, troubleshooting that took me some time and finally i was able to start it. FIM services in services console must be running for UPS sync.

SP2 is one of the stable release. However, it can be updated with July 2014 CU.

[This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/07/24/3586568.aspx) helped me a lot to work with patching.

Hope it help someone else.